# Search for wireless networks within an iPhone application

Tags: iphone, wifi, ssid

How can I search for wireless networks (and connect to one after) within an iPhone application? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Legally, you can't do that. Apple does not provide an API to work with. You could try private frameworks APPLE80221, but your application will be rejected from the Apple Store. Using private frameworks is a breach of Apple's development licence.